# SSRS MySQL Multi-Value Parameters

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

I am trying to use multi-value parameters in SSRS with MySQL but receiving strange results when selecting multiple values for a parameter.

**Parameter Properties**:

- Name: parameter1
- Data Type: Integer (I have tried "Text" but made no difference to the output)
- Selected "Allow multiple values"
- Available Values: (Label: 1, Value: 1) and (Label: 2, Value: 2)

**Dataset Properties**

- Query type: text
- Query: `select column1 from table1 where id IN (?)`
- Parameter Name: ?
- Parameter Value: `=Join(Parameters!parameter1.Value, ",")`

**Result:**

- When selecting a single value: `select column1 from table1 where id IN ('1')`
- When selecting multiple values: `select column1 from table1 where id IN ('1,3')`

**Running on:**

- Windows 10 Pro (1909 - 18363.1316)
- MySQL Community Server (8.0.22)
- MySQL ODBC Connector (8.0.22) - Configured using Unicode Driver
- Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.3)
- Reporting Services Project (2.6.7)

**Observation:**

- Parameter is integer, why is the value sent like a string?
- Multi-value generated *'1,3'* when it should be *'1','3'* or *1,3*

Any suggestions on how to resolve the strange multi-value behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your parameter properties the way it is now.

Try to use this in your **Dataset Properties: Query** > `select column1 from table1 where id IN (@parameter1)` and remove the Parameter Value expression.

Comment: Due to using ODBC connector, I believe it has to be "select column1 from table1 where id IN (?)". Simply taking the @parameter1 produces a "Cannot add multi value query parameter '@parameter1' for dataset 'DataSet1' because it is not supported by the data extension. Looking at the SQL produced, its almost like either SSRS or the MySQL ODBC connector is escaping multi-valued parameters.